# How to develop and test B2C token enrichment with an API connector locally?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am creating a React SPA that will connect to a dotnet Web API backend. I want to use b2c to handle auth.
I want to have endpoints in the API protected based off the claims in the b2c token, also want to check claims in the frontend aswell.

Following along with token enrichment docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector-token-enrichment?pivots=b2c-user-flow
I can use an API connector to enrich the token with additional claims before it is sent back to the client, presumably with a function to provide values from my database in a users table.

If my database will also be hosted in azure, how would I develop and test this locally?

Is this flow the best way to achieve the desired behaviour? If not what are alternatives?

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/mocking-azure-ad-b2c-rest-api-calls-a83c74252be5

Answer (score 0):

I've done two methods when testing 'locally'.

1. Create an Azure Function echo API service in 'cold' mode to reduce cost. This will allow you to easily ping it and it will ping you back the content. You can also add test cases pretty easily. This isn't really 'local' but, it's low cost and allows you to collaborate with multiple team members.
2. Use a free web service like [Post Test Server](http://ptsv2.com/). With a couple clicks you are off and testing with lower effort. The problem with this solution is it is public so do not use any proprietary or confidential information. I've created very complex dot notation in body of REST-API technical profile via custom policies and this was effective testing data formatting and internal business logic.

Last option could be creating a web service locally on your device - I haven't done this end-to-end but you would follow this same process as hosting an application locally with localhost.

Answer (score -1):

You can deploy an Azure database solely for development purposes. Or you can just mock the API response so that you can do some basic e2e testing: SPA -> B2C -> API.